# Why is my reverse() method not working ? Javascript palindrome problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

**Write a Javascript code that checks whether a passed string is palindrome or not?** 
Note: A palindrome is a word or phrase that reads the same backward as forward; eg. madam,racecar, etc.

And this is my code for it.. I'm not sure why it's not working. Can anyone assist?

```js
function is_Palindrome (str){
  
   array1 = str.split('')
  array1_orig = array1.map(a => a)
  array2 = array1.reverse()
  console.log(array1_orig)
 console.log(array2)
  
  

  for (let i = 0; i <array1.length; i++){
    if(array1[i] === array2[i]){
      console.log("a match") 
    }
    else{
      console.log("not a match")
    }
  }


 

}


is_Palindrome("desk")
```

is_Palindrome("desk")

**desk is obviously NOT a palindrome, so it should return "not a match" but the code isn't doing that**

Comment: Best to use [...str] instead of split. Test both with "foo  bar mañana mañana"

Answer (score 1):

In the line `array1.reverse()`, `reverse` will mutate the `array1` object itself. This is cause of your issue.

Actually, you may not need to `reverse` call itself. You can just traverse the elements only till mid point and compare the ith element from start and end.

```js
function is_Palindrome(str) {
  array1 = str.split("");

  const len = array1.length;
  let isMatch = true;

  for (let i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
    if (array1[i] !== array1[len - 1 - i]) {
      isMatch = false;
    }
  }
  return isMatch;
}

console.log("desk - ",is_Palindrome("desk"));
console.log("racecar - ", is_Palindrome("racecar"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**When calling `myArray.reverse()`, `myArray` gets reversed too.**

I fixed the problem by using `array1_orig` instead :

```js
function is_Palindrome (str){
  
   array1 = str.split('')
  array1_orig = array1.map(a => a)

  // Here, you are reversing array1 and storing the result in BOTH array1 and array2.
  array2 = array1.reverse()
  console.log(array1_orig)
 console.log(array2)
  
  

  for (let i = 0; i <array1_orig.length; i++){
    // Change both the line ABOVE and the line BELOW
    if(array1_orig[i] === array2[i]){
      console.log("a match") 
    }
    else{
      console.log("not a match")
    }
  }


 

}

console.log("Testing : DESK")
is_Palindrome("desk")
console.log("Testing : RACECAR")
is_Palindrome("racecar")
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!